# Filtering list elements on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, foo, that looks like the following:

```
   a         b
0  1    [1, 2]
1  2    [1, 2]
2  3  [10, 11]
```

and I am trying to retrieve all the rows that contain the element `[1, 2]` in column `b`. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df['b'].apply(lambda x: x == [1, 2])
df[mask]
```

returns

```
   a       b
0  1  [1, 2]
1  2  [1, 2]
```

If you are new to pandas, the [new user tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) is a good place to start and will cover questions like this.

Comment: `retrieve all the rows that contain the element [1, 2]` is ambiguous in some senses. If OP wants any list that actually `contains` values 1 and 2, then the code should change a little bit ;)